# Cloning and Incrementing Id in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have the following group of

```
<div id="question[1]" class="questions">
  <p> Question: </p>
  <input type="text" id="quizQuestion[1]" name="quizQuestion[1]" placeholder=" Question">
  <input type="text" id="quizAnswer[1][1]" name="quizAnswer[1][1]" placeholder=" First Answer">
  <input type="text" id="quizAnswer[1][2]" name="quizAnswer[1][2]" placeholder=" Second Answer">
  <input type="text" id="quizAnswer[1][3]" name="quizAnswer[1][3]" placeholder=" Third Answer">
  <input type="text" id="quizAnswer[1][4]" name="quizAnswer[1][4]" placeholder=" Fourth Answer">
</div>
```

I want the 1 to turn into 2... etc

I though of recreating each element in the form, but there has to be a better way to this?

```
// last id is found using regex (search for the only number in the id) 
function createQuestion(lastId){
  id = lastId + 1;
  $('<div>').attr({
    id: 'question[id]',
    name: 'bar'
    }).appendTo('form');
    // create the rest of the inputs here (and added inside the created div)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use something like this

```
function NewQuestion(IDChane){
var html = '<div id="question['+ IDChane +']" class="questions">'+
  '<p> Question: </p>'+
  '<input type="text" id="quizQuestion['+ IDChane +']" name="quizQuestion['+ IDChane +']" placeholder=" Question">'+
  '<input type="text" id="quizAnswer['+ IDChane +']['+ IDChane +']" name="quizAnswer['+ IDChane +']['+ IDChane +']" placeholder=" First Answer">'+
  '<input type="text" id="quizAnswer['+ IDChane +']['+ IDChane + 1 +']" name="quizAnswer['+ IDChane +']['+ IDChane + 1 +']" placeholder=" Second Answer">'+
  '<input type="text" id="quizAnswer['+ IDChane +']['+ IDChane + 2 +']" name="quizAnswer['+ IDChane +']['+ IDChane + 2 +']" placeholder=" Third Answer">'+
  '<input type="text" id="quizAnswer['+ IDChane +']['+ IDChane + 3 +']" name="quizAnswer['+ IDChane +']['+ IDChane + 3 +']" placeholder=" Fourth Answer">'+
'</div>';
  $('body').append(html);
}
```

and use it like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        NewQuestion(3);
});
```

[**Working Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/s6rxp15c/5/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are just looking for a regex to parse which number is currently being used, yes?  If so, then doing something like this should work.

```
var id = $('div').prop('id');
var matches = id.match(/(\d+)/g);
//matches will contain an array of numbers from the id
```

So if you are targeting an element with `id="quizAnswer[1][3]"`, matches will be `[1, 3]`.  Targeting `id="quizQuestion[2]"` will just have matches as `[2]`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need all those IDs? Using a `name` attribute should just be sufficient. You can use use the power of jQuery; listen for a click event on a button or other element and then clone the first element, count the existing questions and determine the new question id and then add the new question.

```js
$(function() {
    $('.add-question').on('click', function() {
        var q = $('.quiz > .questions'),
            n = q.length + 1,
            c = q.first().clone();
        c.attr('id', function() {
            return this.id.replace(/\d+/, n);
        })
        .find('[id]').attr('id', function() {
            return this.id.replace(/\d+/, n);
        })
        .attr('name', function() {
            return this.name.replace(/\d+/, n);
        })
        .end()
        .appendTo('.quiz');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="quiz">
<div id="question[1]" class="questions">
  <p> Question: </p>
  <input type="text" id="quizQuestion[1]" name="quizQuestion[1]" placeholder=" Question">
  <input type="text" id="quizAnswer[1][1]" name="quizAnswer[1][1]" placeholder=" First Answer">
  <input type="text" id="quizAnswer[1][2]" name="quizAnswer[1][2]" placeholder=" Second Answer">
  <input type="text" id="quizAnswer[1][3]" name="quizAnswer[1][3]" placeholder=" Third Answer">
  <input type="text" id="quizAnswer[1][4]" name="quizAnswer[1][4]" placeholder=" Fourth Answer">
</div>
</div>
<button class="add-question">Add Question</button>
```